# Add hour to archive link?

Tags: archives

I have searched about this on internet but hopeless.

The default of archive link is yoursite.com/year/month/day . My site is about news so i want to add hour to archive link to become yoursite.com/year/month/day/hour .

How could I ?

Regard

Answer (score 1):

[Permalinks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) or the pretty url of your posts be set under permalink in settings. there you can use `%hour%` or [many other available tags in your url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Structure_Tags)